# How to make several fields editable in React and Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have an object in my redux state

```
const obj = {
 name: 'name',
 age: 2,
 place: 0,
}
```

I show these values on the page but I want to make two of them editable so that the object can be updated.

For that I'm basically getting values from two inputs and sending them to my `action`

```
export const saveEditedData = data => dispatch => {
  dispatch({
    type: CHANGE_DATA,
    data,
  });
 }
```

and then in reducer

```
 case 'CHANGE_DATA': 
      return {
        ...state,
        obj: {
         ...state.obj,
         name: action.data.name,
         age: action.data.age,
       }
    }
```

The problem that I'm facing is that if one value is updated and another is not then after this action my second value in empty.

My question is what is a good way to determine which field is changed and update only it?

So far I only came up with putting `if else` in action to dispatch certain thing. Maybe there is a better way?

Comment: for form data I would suggest using something like Formik or redux-form

Comment: @Antoni4 no, it is not a form, just separate inputs on the page

Answer (score 0):

You can 1. make each field update with individual actions, `changeName`, `changeAge`, etc, or 2. filter the action payload to get rid of the unwanted values before putting them in your `obj`:

```
 case 'CHANGE_DATA': 
      return {
        ...state,
        obj: {
         ...state.obj,
         ...action.data.filter(el => !!el)
       }
    }
```

(the `!!` notation is converting the array elements to booleans when filtering, not strictly necessary but sanitary)

EDIT: Sorry I misunderstood your data shape, see comments.

Comment: I don't have an array to filter though, my data is also an object

Comment: @Dockson if "action.data.filter(el => !!el)" returns an array, how are you merging that with "state.obj"?

Comment: @Allan if you are using lodash you can probably achieve what Dockson is suggesting with "_.pick(obj, _.identity);"